# Android gradle sync : Could not get resource firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.4-javadoc.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I'm using Android Studio last version 3.2.1

I've created a sample project for testing the problem I have on my main app. I thought at first it was a thing of my app, but I get the same problem on the very simple test app.

So here app the important dependencies of the test app :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Gradle sync works fine.
But as soon as I add these 2 lines in dependencies

```
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Gradle sync generate 2 warnings about 2 missing javadocs :

```
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.4/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.4-javadoc.jar

org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.6/firebase-core-16.0.6-javadoc.jar'
```

It's a warning, OK, but on my main app which have almost 100 flavors, gradle generate 200 failing http requests which delays the gradle sync significantly.

Is there a way I coud ask gradle to stop requesting these files ?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, don't edit it into the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a couple of tests, it seems that the problem is with

```
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

I replaced it with

```
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```

And I don't get the warnings anymore. It seems that somebody forgot to provide all the javadocs for last version 16.0.6 of firebase-core. I can live with not using the last version, so I'll use 16.0.5 to avoid this warning.